# Buscando Threads Ativas

Tags: java, thread, multithreading

Estou com o seguinte problema, onde tenho um `for()` que abre 17 threads e preciso recuperar, em outra thread ( 18ª ) as thread ativas que abri anteriormente e verificar quais das 17 ainda estão ativas.
Dei uma olhada pela internet, porém não encontrei nenhuma solução plausível para o meu problema.

**Qual seria a melhor solução para recuperar as threads ativas que abri anteriormente?**

Segue o Codigo:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 500; i+=30){
  Runnable r = new Async(empresa,i,30);
  Thread t = new Thread(r);             
  t.start();
}
```

Comment: Tem como você adicionar como está fazendo isso(iniciar as 17 threads)?

Comment: Poderia adicionar as treads para uma array

Comment: Possivel solução: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26540115/5524514

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme e Diego.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bom, encontrei a solução atribuindo cada thread criada a um arrayList, onde posteriormente verifico se ela está ativa, pegando cada thread da lista.

O Codigo ficou assim:

```
List<Thread> threadArray = new ArrayList<Thread>();

for(int i = 1; i <= 500; i+=30){
    Runnable r = new Async(empresa,i,30);
    Thread t = new Thread(r);               
    threadArray.add(t);
    t.start();      
}
```

Posteriormente na outra Thread:

```
for (Thread t : threadArray) {                  
    System.out.println("Ativo: "+t.isAlive());
}
```